# Footprint for 12.3x12.3mm SMD inductor

Tags: pcb-design, inductor, surface-mount, kicad, footprint

I want to incorporate this inductor:
https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Inductors-SMD_SHOU-HAN-CYH127-150UH_C2929506.html
in my project.

Datasheet it here: https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2201121430_SHOU-HAN-CYH127-150UH_C2929506.pdf

According to the website, it has an `SMD,12.3x12.3mm` package. Searching the Kicad's `Inductor SMD` footprint library, nothing matches with the string `12.3x12.3`.

Does someone has in mind which footprint matches this inductor?

Answer (score 2):

Inductors are probably the most varied components in SMD packages. It is pointless to search for the exact match by package size in most cases.

Instead check the datasheet for recommended *pad layout*, especially the distance between the pads. Then simply browse through available packages and find the best fit.

If there is nothing suitable, then make a copy of the closest available and modify it to datasheet dimensions. It only takes couple minutes after all.